# Delete a Json line using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

My API retrieve a Json like this :

```
{
 "name": "API",
 "count": 30,
 "newdata": true,
 "lastrunstatus": "success",
 "thisversionstatus": "success",
 "thisversionrun": "Mon Sep 07 2015 20:31:07 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
 "results": {
 "collection1": [
  {
    "name": "Item1",
    "power": "210",
    "name": {
      "href": "http://picture.item42.com/item42.html",
      "text": "Hammer of god"
    },
    "desc": "Iron Hammer",
    "index": 1,
    "url": "http://picture.item42.com/"
  },
  {
      "name": "Item2",
    "power": "230",
    "name": {
      "href": "http://picture.item42.com/item43.html",
      "text": "Sword of god"
    },
    "desc": "Iron sword",
    "index": 1,
    "url": "http://picture.item43.com/"
  }
 ]
}
```

I would like to delete the line "url" for each one, and delete le "href" property for the name to have "name" : "Hammer of god";

I try this and many other way (first step to delete the url): 
data contains the Json that I copied upper

```
function transform(data) {
var yourArray = data.results.collection1;
    var p = 0;
    var i = 0;
    var destArr=[];
        var srcArr=yourArray;
        for(i in srcArr){ 
         if(srcArr[i].url) 
            destArr[p]=srcArr[i];
            p++;
      }
    srcArr=destArr;
  return srcArr;
}
```

Maybe its better to use data.results.collection1.filter ?
actually my code return the json without the header but still with the url row

Comment: How thr can be two keys with same name "name"

Comment: @user1386579 Your right there cannot be two `name`'s, what happens in this case is the value of `name` takes the value of the last item in the object. So for `collection1[0]` the value of `name` would be: `{href: "http://picture.item42.com/item42.html", text: "Hammer of god"}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply go through your `json.result.collection1` and remove `href` on each `name` and `url`:

```
for(item in json.results.collection1) {
    delete json.results.collection1[item].name.href
    delete json.results.collection1[item].url;
}
```

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/evhb3m6p/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `delete` keyword to delete a property from the JSON.

```
var jsonObj = JSON.parse('your json string');
delete jsobObj.whateveryYourpropertyName;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var json = document.getElementById('json').value;
var obj = JSON.parse(json);

obj.results.collection1.forEach(function(entry) {
    delete entry.url;
    delete entry.name.href;
});

document.getElementById('result').value = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/753ee7L1/)

Answer (score 1):

you should use the [JSON `delete`](http://jsonapi.org/format/) method for what you want to achieve:
Where `data` is your json object:

```
data.results.collection1.forEach(function(el) {
   delete el.url
   delete el.name.href
});
```

You can simply use a second forEach loop in case you need to iterate through multiple collections.

Comment: Appreciate, the advice for the multiple collections and it work well

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
jsonData.results.collection1.map(function(obj, index){
  delete obj.url;
  obj.name = obj.name.text;
  return obj;
});
console.log(jsonData);
```

Comment: Why do you save the new JSON to `finalData` but then overwrite it? This seems unnecessarily complicated.